# What would be the ideal way to format a list into columns, where they remain alphabetical vertically?

Tags: jquery, list, foreach, each

Say one has a list of U.S. states, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Alabama</li>
    <li>Alaska</li>
    <li>Arizona</li>
    <li>Arkansas</li>
    <li>California</li>
    <li>Colorado</li>
    <li>Connecticut</li>
    <li>Delaware</li>
    <!-- and so on with all 50 -->
</ul>
```

It's easy enough to get them formatted into four columns with just CSS:

```
li {float:left; width:25%;}
li:nth-of-type(4n+5) {clear:left;}
```

That creates four columns, and ensures the 5th item always clears the previous elements.

However, this will result in the first column starting with Alabama, the second Alaska, the third Arizona, and the fourth Arkansas.

Instead, I am trying to figure out the best way to make all four columns contain relatively equal amounts of states (50 / 4 = 12.5 so columns 1 - 3 would contain 13 list items, and the final column would contain the remaining 11 items), and at the same time, the first column should contain the FIRST 13 states (ie, Alabama - Illinois), the SECOND contain the 14th - 27th states (Indiana - Montana), and so on.

Leaning toward jQuery for this, thus far I've made it to:

```
var list_items_count = $('li').length, // get the total number of list items
    even_list_math   = list_items_count / 4, // divide that by 4 columns
    even_list_amount = Math.ceil(even_list_math), // round the number up
    column_1_start   = 0, // it doesn't = 1 because 0 = 1
    column_2_start   = even_list_amount, // 1st item in column 2
    column_3_start   = even_list_amount * 2, // 1st item in column 3
    column_4_start   = even_list_amount * 3; // 1st item in column 4

    $('li').each(function(index, val) {
        if (index == column_1_start) {
            $(this).before('<li><ul>');
        } else if (index == column_2_start || index == column_3_start || index == column_4_start) {
            $(this).before('</ul></li><li><ul>');
        } else if (index == list_items_count) {
            $(this).after('</ul></li>');
        }
    });
```

But when I do this, jQuery wants to close my elements.

So instead of:

```
<ul>
    <li><ul> <!-- this should be created in the first $(this).before() statement -->
        <li>Alabama</li>
...
</ul>
```

jQuery is automatically closing those elements:

```
<ul>
    <li><ul></ul><li> <!-- the closing UL and LI tags shouldn't be here -->
        <li>Alabama</li>
...
</ul>
```

Can I prevent it from doing so? Or is there something else wrong with my jQuery that needs fixed or optimized?

**Edit**: While this example shows 50 states, the content that I'm working with is dynamic. So it could be a list of 1000 types of vegetables, 3 countries, 28 ways to keep your man, etc. Thus all of this...

I'm also experimenting with using `.wrap()` but with no luck yet.

```
var li_elems = $('li'),
    li_arr = $.makeArray( li_elems );
    while(li_arr.length) {
        li_arr.splice(0,even_list_amount);
    }
    $.each(li_arr, function(index, val) {
        $(this).wrap('<ul class="test"></ul>');
    });
```

Comment: Can't you just divide your `li` into four `div`, since there's a finite and known number of states?

Comment: @Marxtai, sorry, clarified that the initial list is dynamic. It won't always be states, or the number 50.

Comment: @Nathan https://jsfiddle.net/pcwbahyj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use combination of [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/). [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0pLbp27/).

The solution is straight forward.

```
$(function() {
    var items = $('#list > li'),
    count = items.length,
    columns = 4,
    perColumn = Math.ceil(count/columns);

  for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    items
      .slice(i*perColumn, (i+1)*perColumn) //group
      .wrapAll('<li class="column"><ul class="inner"/></li>') //wrap
  }
})
```

Or if you don't care about old browsers you could use [CSS3 multiple-columns layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/emhuxue1/).

```
ul {
  column-count: 4; //important part
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect with the jQuery answer, and thank you for reminding me about CSS3 columns! That's probably the easier way to go. :)